# Embedd Image In JIRA Word Export

Tags: jira, velocity

According to the JIRA documentation you can custommise the Word export by modifying the velocity templates in `atlassian-jira-webapp.war/WEB-INF/classes/templates/plugins/issueviews`

https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirakb/customise-word-export-template-for-jira-applications-296094716.html

How do I embed an image in the document so that it is portable and doesn't have any image links to the JIRA webpage since sometimes they don't render if you don't have access.

Answer (score 0):

Embedding an image inside HTML is possible, using the [data URI feature](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs). Here is [a short tutorial](http://qnimate.com/understanding-and-using-data-uris/). But there are browser-dependent size limits... and one has still to check that this data URI image will be preserved through the JIRA Word export.

Comment: I tried that with base64 encoding but maybe the transformation engine JIRA uses doesn't recognise it even though it works in a browser.